# Can't press Ctrl + D to reach EOF

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, pointers, mergesort

Hi I'm new to C so still being confused about a few things but getting there. I'm trying to implement mergesort and i think I've implemented it correctly.

When I compile and run the program it waits for me to give it input. That's fine I'll give it 5 4 3 2 1. Then I go to press Ctrl + D and nothing happens. It shows the ^D at the start of the terminal but doesn't reach end of file and spit me out my sorted array. Not too sure why this is happening? I've tried to debug it with printlines but can't seem to figure out why. Could it be something to do with scanf? Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define ARRAY_MAX 30000

void merge(int *a, int *w, int length){
    int i = 0;
    int j = (length/2);
    int k = 0;

    while ((i < length/2) && (j < length)){
            if (a[i] < a[j]){
                    w[k] = a[i];
                    i++;
                    k++;
            }
            else if (a[j] < a[j]){
                    w[k] = a[j];
                    j++;
                    k++;
            }
    }
    if (i >= length/2){
            for (; j < length; i++){
                    w[k] = a[j];
                    k++;
            }
    }
    else{
            for (; i < length/2; i++){
                    w[k] = a[i];
                    k++;
            }
    }
 }

/*mergesort, requires a workspace*/
void merge_sort(int *a, int *w, int length){

    int i;
    if (length < 2){
            return;
    }
    merge_sort(a, w, length/2);
    merge_sort(a+(length/2), w, (length-(length/2)));

    merge(a,w,length);

    /*copy workspace back to original array*/
    for (i=0; i < length; i++){
            a[i] = w[i];
    }
}

int main(void){
    int my_array[ARRAY_MAX];
    int workspace[ARRAY_MAX];
    clock_t start, end;
    int i;
    int count = 0;

    while ((count < ARRAY_MAX) && (1==scanf("%d", &my_array[count]))){
            count++;
    }

    printf("debug");
    start = clock();
    merge_sort(my_array, workspace, count);
    end = clock();

    for (i=0; i < count; i++){
            printf("%d\n", my_array[i]);
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "%d %f\n", count, (end-start)/(double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Try pressing `CTRL+Z`

Comment: It just says stopped. So maybe there's smething slightly off on my code but I can't figure out what it is.

Comment: Which OS are you using? And is the error "filename.exe has stopped working blah blah"?

Comment: I'm using macosx with a Unix prompt. I have a feeling it's something to do with my code as previous sorting programs I've made have spat out the sorted array after I press ctrl D.

Screenshot of what happens. Notes I'm pressing Ctrl D and nothing's happening so I'm pressing control C

http://iforce.co.nz/i/n0aakye2.hdg.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not the problem of Ctrl+D not work but your algorithm. Please change

```
while ((i < length/2) && (j < length)){
        if (a[i] < a[j]){
                w[k] = a[i];
                i++;
                k++;
        }
        else if (a[j] < a[j]){
                w[k] = a[j];
                j++;
                k++;
        }
}
```

to

```
while ((i < length/2) && (j < length)){
        if (a[i] < a[j]){
                w[k] = a[i];
                i++;
                k++;
        }
        else {
                w[k] = a[j];
                j++;
                k++;
        }
}
```

Since `a[j] < a[j]` is always false, it will loop infinitely.
And your mergesort algorithm is not correct too. For more detail you can see the sample code of [merge_sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort).